# VSCode: How to ask for password in terminal instead of pop-up/tab?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

My students and I have been doing remote pair programming with VSCode with the LiveShare extension. Previously, when pushing to remote repositories, the password would be requested in the terminal, which we can share and is what we want.

Now about half of my students are getting [this pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOU23.png) and the host's remote partner cannot access the input field to type in their password themselves.

This of course raises concerns of password security, so I'm looking for a way to revert this behavior to request the password in the built-in terminal instead of a VSCode pop-up/modal/whatever that thing is called.

Additional information: we're using HTTPS, not SSH. We would prefer to not us SSH if possible.

I've been trying to find answers on the internet, but a majority the questions/solutions involve SSH or are looking to remove the need to use passwords, and does not address the pop-up that requests the password. I've also looked through the settings in VSCode, but I couldn't find anything regarding this behavior.

Comment: Check Terminal Authentication in VSCode settings for Git.

Answer (score 3):

In vscode open the settings editor

```
File > Preferences > Settings
```

> Search for **Terminal Authentication** and uncheck.
>
> Also search for **Git Authentication** and uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

From the v1.45 [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_45#_source-control):

> #### GitHub authentication for GitHub repositories
>
> VS Code now has automatic GitHub authentication against GitHub repositories. You can now clone, pull, push to and from public and private repositories without configuring any credential manager in your system. Even Git commands invoked in the Integrated Terminal, for example `git push`, are now automatically authenticated against your GitHub account.
>
> You can disable GitHub authentication with the `git.githubAuthentication` setting. You can also disable the terminal authentication integration with the `git.terminalAuthentication` setting.

From the [default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings):

```
{
  ...

  // Controls whether to enable VS Code to be the authentication handler for git processes spawned in the integrated terminal. Note: terminals need to be restarted to pick up a change in this setting.
  "git.terminalAuthentication": true,

  // Controls whether to enable automatic GitHub authentication for git commands within VS Code.
  "github.gitAuthentication": true,

  ...
}
```

You can set either or both of those to `false` in your `settings.json`.